# group_concat with left join is way too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a song library and a working query that joins multiple tables and returns all of song_id, song_title etc into one big table like this:

```
song_id             song_title          song_vocal          song_composer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   Hello Boy           John                Mike
2                   Hello Girl          Jim                 Dave
2                   Hello Girl          Tom                 Dave
```

And I want to combine songs with multiple vocal/composer into one row like this:

```
song_id             song_title          song_vocal          song_composer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   Hello Boy           John                Mike
2                   Hello Girl          Jim,Tom             Dave
```

I did it with the group_concat() function, but it's way too slow. Without the group_concat, my query only takes 0.06 seconds. With the function, it takes 3 seconds. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
songs.song_id,
songs.title as Song_Title,
group_concat(DISTINCT a1.artist_name ORDER BY a1.artist_name DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) as Vocals,
group_concat(DISTINCT a2.artist_name ORDER BY a2.artist_name DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) as Composers    

FROM songs

left join song_vocals ON song_vocals.song_id = songs.song_id
left join artists a1 ON song_vocals.artist_id = a1.artist_id

left join song_composers on songs.song_id = song_composers.song_id
left join artists a2  on a2.artist_id = song_composers.artist_id

GROUP BY songs.song_id
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course this is too slow.  You are generating a Cartesian product and then removing the duplicates.

I would recommend replacing the logic with correlated subqueries:

```
select s.song_id, s.title as Song_Title,
       (select group_concat(a.artist_name order by a.artist_name DESC separator ',' ) 
        from song_vocals sv join 
             artists a 
             on sv.artist_id = a.artist_id
        where sv.song_id = s.song_id
       ) as Vocals,
       (select group_concat(a.artist_name order by a.artist_name desc separator ',' ) 
        from song_composers sc join 
             artists a 
             on sc.artist_id = a.artist_id
        where sc.song_id = s.song_id
       ) as Composers    
from songs s;
```

This can also take advantage of indexes on `song_composers(song_id, artist_id)` and `song_vocals(song_id, artist_id)`.  I also removed the `distinct` from `group_concat()`.  That should no longer be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm, the query ran instantly. So the logic is to do the concat while there're indexes, instead of doing it at the end?

Comment: @reddy . . . I guess you could express it like that.  A correlated subquery can make better use of indexes than an aggregation query.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with multiple many-to-many relationships, the relationships almost always have to be (sub)queried separately and then merged.

```
SELECT s.song_id, s.title as Song_Title, v.Vocals, c.Composers    
FROM songs AS s
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT song_id
        , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.artist_name 
                       ORDER BY a.artist_name DESC 
                       SEPARATOR ',' 
          ) as Vocals
   FROM song_vocals AS sv
   LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON sv.artist_id = a.artist_id
   GROUP BY sv.song_id
) AS v ON s.song_id = v.song_id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT sc.song_id
        , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.artist_name 
                       ORDER BY a.artist_name DESC 
                       SEPARATOR ',' 
          ) as Composers
   FROM song_composers AS sc
   LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON sc.artist_id = a.artist_id
   GROUP BY sc.song_id
) AS c ON s.song_id = c.song_id
;
```

Comment: There's a typo, it should be "as Composers" instead of "as Vocals" in the second left join. But it doesn't work, it returns a gigantic result with repeating song_title and vocals.

Comment: Sorry about that, copy-paste typo. As far as the gigantic result; make sure you used my previous edit that added the join conditions I forgot (`...AS v ON s.song_id = v.song_id` and `...AS c ON s.song_id = v.song_id`)

Comment: @reddy Oh, dammit, it was another typo `...AS c ON s.song_id = v.song_id` **should have been** `...AS c ON s.song_id = c.song_id`